# COUNTIF across multiple cells based on criteria from another cell?

Tags: excel, vlookup, countif

I've got a fairly large spreadsheet with survey data that I'm trying to summarize.  The first tab of the spreadsheet has all the survey data and I'm trying to summarize on the second tab.

Column A in my second tab will have all the unique store numbers listed.  I'd like Column B of the second tab to list the number of times a customer answered "Very Satisfied" in columns R through Z on the first tab for a particular store.  The store number is also listed on the first tab in column DY.

I've never tried nesting combining COUNTIF and VLOOKUP before or maybe that's not even the best way to do this.  My feeble attempt looks like this

=COUNTIF(Sheet1!DY:DY,VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!R:Z,0,FALSE))

And, of course, this returns "#VALUE!".  I know I need "Very Satisfied" in there somewhere but I can't wrap my head around the nesting.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT()

NOTE: I am using full columns here but it would work better if one would limit the references to just the rows that have data.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!DY:DY=A2)*(Sheet1!R:Z="Very Satisfied"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help.  I tried this on my laptop for the first store and it seems to work.  So I tried to copy/paste the formula to the rest of column B and I got a message that Excel ran out of resources.  This is on a laptop that's only about a year old with an i7, 16gb of RAM and an SSD.  I copied the file to my desktop computer for a little more horsepower and it seems to be calculating - it's at least got a % calculated going.

Comment: @Jeff hence the note about limiting the full columns to just the rows with data.  This is an array formula and it is doing 10 calcs for every row in the formula.  If you limit it to the data and it is only 1000 rows then each formula is only doing 10,000 calcs per, but leaving the full column references it is doing more than 10,000,000 per formula instance.

Comment: Thanks.  How would one limit the number of rows it checks?  There are approximately 41,000 rows right now but I expect it to grow.  Can I set an upper limit of 100k or something that I know it won't go past?

Comment: `Sheet1!$DY$1:$DY$100000` and so forth.

Comment: Thanks again Scott, I will play with it and read up on sumproduct as I've never used it before.